# something went wrong when I tried to apply #define in a function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I tried to apply `#define` in a conditional statement, however, it seems that something went wrong.

```
// The mode is forward by default
#define FOR

if ( mode == "forward")
{
    clog << "mode == forward" << endl;
}

else if (mode == "reverse")
{
    clog << "Enter reverse" << endl;

    #define REV
    #undef FOR
}
else 
{
    cerr << "NOT A VALID MODE (FORWARD OR REVERSE)" << endl;
}

#ifdef FOR
cout << "Switch to forward mode." << endl;
#endif

#ifdef REV
cout << "Switch to reverse mode." << endl;
#endif
```

and the output is

```
mode == forward
Switch to reverse mode
```

Isn't this contradictory?

I think it may be the problem of compiling.
After precompiling, the code looks like this

```
int main()
{
    string mode = "forward";
    if ( mode == "forward")
    {
        clog << "mode == forward" << endl;
    }

    else if (mode == "reverse")
    {
        clog << "Enter reverse" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "NOT A VALID MODE (FORWARD OR REVERSE)" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Switch to reverse mode." << endl;
}
```

I'm just new to C++, can anyone tell me why this could happen?

Comment: That `define REV` knows absolutely nothing about the `if`-statement it's inside. The preprocessor knows nothing about the language and its control flow, only bits of raw text and how to replace them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Preprocessor macros are not the right tool for it.

Comment: Seems like you need to learn the difference between compile-time and run-time, and to understand what preprocessor directives do.

Comment: Indentation is a powerful force of deception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have been clearer in stating WHAT you want.
Using #define to alter the behavior of your code can be done but ususally only needed if you really want to enable/disable code at compile time (e.g. for release/debug, gcc/clang/MSVC compiler things). And even that should be reduced to a minimum.

In C++ try to stay as typesafe as you can and the preprocessor is usually not that either. If you have to make decissions at compile time then you can also use function templates.

```
#include <iostream>

// if you got options make an enum
// this will even prevent you from
// being able selecting wrong modes ever
// #define will NEVER give you that guarantee
enum class modes
{
    reverse,
    forward
};

template<modes mode>
void select_at_compile_time()
{
    if constexpr (mode == modes::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << "compile time reverse\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "compile time forward\n";
    }
}

void select_mode_at_runtime(modes mode)
{
    if (mode == modes::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << "runtime reverse\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "runtime forward\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    select_at_compile_time<modes::forward>();
    select_mode_at_runtime(modes::reverse);
    return 0;
}
```